# KuduSink<MyModel> fails to start

Tags: flink-streaming, apache-kudu, apache-bahir

I'm trying to write a ETL pipeline from kafka to HDFS using flink.
I'm using the bahir KuduSink and a PojoOperationMapper
It throws an exception before starting.  I've included my code, pom, and exception stack trace.
Is there something obvious I'm missing?

```
package pipeline.poc.model;

import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class MyModel{
    
    private String msgKey;
    private String msgData;
}
```

Pipeline mapping

```
package pipeline.poc;

import org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.MapFunction;
import org.apache.flink.shaded.jackson2.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature;
import org.apache.flink.shaded.jackson2.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import org.apache.flink.shaded.jackson2.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.apache.flink.shaded.jackson2.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode;


public class MessageMapFunction implements MapFunction<ObjectNode, MyModel> {
    
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    private final ObjectMapper mapper;

    public MessageMapFunction() {
        super();
        mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
    }

    @Override
    public MyModel map(ObjectNode value) throws Exception {
        JsonNode msgValue =  value.get("value");
        return mapper.convertValue(msgValue, MyModel.class);
    }

}
```

The pipeline program

```
package pipeline.poc;

import java.util.Properties;

import org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.MapFunction;
import org.apache.flink.connectors.kudu.connector.KuduTableInfo;
import org.apache.flink.connectors.kudu.connector.writer.KuduWriterConfig;
import org.apache.flink.connectors.kudu.connector.writer.PojoOperationMapper;
import org.apache.flink.connectors.kudu.connector.writer.AbstractSingleOperationMapper.KuduOperation;
import org.apache.flink.connectors.kudu.streaming.KuduSink;
import org.apache.flink.shaded.jackson2.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStream;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumer;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.KafkaDeserializationSchema;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.util.serialization.JSONKeyValueDeserializationSchema;

public class Pipeline {

    private final StreamExecutionEnvironment env;
    private final KuduWriterConfig kuduConfig;
    private final PojoOperationMapper<MyModel> operationMapper;
    private final KuduSink<MyModel> kuduSink;
    private final KafkaDeserializationSchema<ObjectNode> schema;
    private final FlinkKafkaConsumer<ObjectNode> consumer;
    private final String[] columns = {"key", "value"};
    private final MapFunction<ObjectNode, MyModel> messageMapFunction;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        new Pipeline().run();

    }
    
    Pipeline() {
        env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
        schema = new JSONKeyValueDeserializationSchema(false);
        
        kuduConfig = KuduWriterConfig.Builder
                .setMasters("localhost:7051,localhost:7151,localhost:7251")
                .build();
        
        operationMapper = new PojoOperationMapper<> (
                MyModel.class,
                columns, 
                KuduOperation.INSERT);
        
        kuduSink = new KuduSink<>(
                kuduConfig, 
                KuduTableInfo.forTable("TOYTABLE"), 
                operationMapper);
        
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
        props.setProperty("group.id", "pipeline.demo");
        consumer = new FlinkKafkaConsumer<>(
                "pipeline.demo", 
                schema, 
                props);
        
        messageMapFunction = new MessageMapFunction();
    }

    public void run() {
        
        DataStream<ObjectNode> dataStream = env.addSource(consumer);
        DataStream<MyModel> messageStream = dataStream.map(messageMapFunction);

//      just printing the mapped stream works
//      messageStream.print();
//      Adding the kuduSink throw an exception
        messageStream.addSink(kuduSink);
        
        
        try {
            env.execute("Pipeline Demo");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

It throw this exception

```
ERROR StatusLogger No Log4j 2 configuration file found. Using default configuration (logging only errors to the console), or user programmatically provided configurations. Set system property 'log4j2.debug' to show Log4j 2 internal initialization logging. See https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html for instructions on how to configure Log4j 2
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.flink.api.java.ClosureCleaner (file:/Users/smitopher/.m2/repository/org/apache/flink/flink-core/1.13.1/flink-core-1.13.1.jar) to field java.util.Properties.serialVersionUID
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.flink.api.java.ClosureCleaner
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.flink.api.common.InvalidProgramException: [Ljava.lang.reflect.Field;@1095f122 is not serializable. The object probably contains or references non serializable fields.
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.ClosureCleaner.clean(ClosureCleaner.java:164)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.ClosureCleaner.clean(ClosureCleaner.java:132)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.ClosureCleaner.clean(ClosureCleaner.java:132)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.ClosureCleaner.clean(ClosureCleaner.java:69)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment.clean(StreamExecutionEnvironment.java:2053)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStream.clean(DataStream.java:203)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStream.addSink(DataStream.java:1243)
    at pipeline.poc.Pipeline.run(Pipeline.java:75)
    at pipeline.poc.Pipeline.main(Pipeline.java:34)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: java.lang.reflect.Field
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1185)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1379)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1175)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:349)
    at org.apache.flink.util.InstantiationUtil.serializeObject(InstantiationUtil.java:624)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.ClosureCleaner.clean(ClosureCleaner.java:143)
    ... 8 more
```

pom.xml

```
<!-- Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more contributor 
    license agreements. See the NOTICE file distributed with this work for additional 
    information regarding copyright ownership. The ASF licenses this file to 
    you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not use 
    this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy of 
    the License at http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0 Unless required 
    by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the 
    License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS 
    OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the specific 
    language governing permissions and limitations under the License. -->
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>pipeline.poc</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka-flink-pipeline</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>Flink Quickstart Job</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <flink.version>1.13.1</flink.version>
        <target.java.version>11</target.java.version>
        <scala.binary.version>2.11</scala.binary.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>${target.java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>${target.java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
        <log4j.version>2.12.1</log4j.version>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>apache.snapshots</id>
            <name>Apache Development Snapshot Repository</name>
            <url>https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Apache Flink dependencies -->
        <!-- These dependencies are provided, because they should not be packaged 
            into the JAR file. -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-java</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-streaming-java_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-clients_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Add connector dependencies here. They must be in the default scope 
            (compile). -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-connector-kafka_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Add logging framework, to produce console output when running in the 
            IDE. -->
        <!-- These dependencies are excluded from the application JAR by default. -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.bahir</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-connector-kudu_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>1.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.20</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>

            <!-- Java Compiler -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${target.java.version}</source>
                    <target>${target.java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- We use the maven-shade plugin to create a fat jar that contains all 
                necessary dependencies. -->
            <!-- Change the value of <mainClass>...</mainClass> if your program entry 
                point changes. -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <!-- Run shade goal on package phase -->
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifactSet>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>org.apache.flink:force-shading</exclude>
                                    <exclude>com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305</exclude>
                                    <exclude>org.slf4j:*</exclude>
                                    <exclude>org.apache.logging.log4j:*</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </artifactSet>
                            <filters>
                                <filter>
                                    <!-- Do not copy the signatures in the META-INF folder. Otherwise, 
                                        this might cause SecurityExceptions when using the JAR. -->
                                    <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </filter>
                            </filters>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>com.apple.pipeline.poc.StreamingJob</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>

                <!-- This improves the out-of-the-box experience in Eclipse by resolving 
                    some warnings. -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                            <pluginExecutions>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>[3.1.1,)</versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>shade</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <ignore />
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>[3.1,)</versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                                            <goal>compile</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <ignore />
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                            </pluginExecutions>
                        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: I'm running Kafka and Kuru locally from containers
I have a Spring Boot app that writes messages to Kafka as the source for the pipeline
I have an existing Kuru table built as the pipeline sink

Comment: Well... The issue appears to be with the Bahir PojoOperationMapper.  I created my own operations manager class that extended AbstractSingleOperationMapper<MyModel> and now everything works